# Execute JavaScript inside WebView source

Tags: javascript, react-native

Anyone knows how (if possible) to execute JS "inside" a WebView in React Native?

**The scenario:** I have this remote logon page (website) displayed in my WebView, and this website has a sequence of events that happens corresponding to the user activity. All events fire one callback each, which the WebView must listen on (not an issue).
Within each callback there is a reference to a JavaScript function, that must be called inside the WebView (that's the issue!).
So from my React Native app, I need to call this JavaScript function, that's placed on the website page (source) that's loaded in my WebView.

**What I have:** I listen for the callbacks with [`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onshouldstartloadwithrequest) and manipulate the behaviour of the WebView with this and it works great.
Regarding JavaScript execution I have tried the method `getWebViewHandle` but that didn't do it, at least not from my seat.
I looked at `injectedJavaScript` property too, but the problem is that I don't know what JavaScript to execute before the callbacks are fired.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

**November 2018 Update**

Webview component now supports *injectJavaScript* and *injectedJavaScript* props.

Example:

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native' }}
  injectedJavaScript="window.alert('first message')"
  injectJavaScript={() => {
    return "window.alert('second message')";
  }}
/>
```

**Original answer**

Calling javascript methods inside a Webview is possible with iOS and Android native components. But required API for javascript execution is currently not provided by react-native. You can see the discussion in [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1191).

However, there is a [3rd party module](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge) that's providing bi-directional communication between your app and a Webview. You can start using it after integrating some native code into your project.

Comment: As of Nov 2018, there are parameters available on the Webview React Native component to inject javascript inside the pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [good article covering how to communicate with content within a React Native Webview](https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/communicating-between-react-native-and-the-webview-ac14b8b8b91a) using injectJavascript API as well as onMessage/postMessage.